# Blender Texture Bake Problems

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

Hopefully someone can help. I tried to ask this in the question section, but I am not permitted to start new topics yet. This is partially a Unity question and partially a Blender question. I will be asking in both places. Thank you all in advance for any help.

I'm new to CG and have been self educating for the past few months. I have progressed fairly well, but I can't seem to get exactly what I want with my objects when they are displayed in Unity. I would like them to appear as they do in Blender when they are rendered, but I can't seem to duplicate the effects in Unity.

The biggest issue I have seems to somehow relate to scaling the texture prior to baking. Objects that do not require scaling prior to the bake to get the texture to display properly (e.g...Rocks) import to Unity perfectly, but Objects that require scaling (e.g....BlockWalls) to get the texture to display correctly go haywire when they are baked (Rock and Ruins were both baked the same way, only difference was the scaling, which I used a Texture Coordinate [UV] and Mapping Vector in Blender to position and scale). The textures show as a black field interspersed with small images of the textured UV unwrapped faces at various intervals on the surface of the object when applied in unity. I believe this is some type of issue with the interplay of light baking to the surface and scaling.

I am able to get the textures into Unity just fine without baking and just save the image files and the .blend directly into Unity, but that's where the texture quality loss is happening. I have also tried various other modifications within Unity to attempt to restore some of the quality lost (e.g.... Bump/Diffuse. Parallax Diffuse, Self Illuminated Bump Diffuse/Parallax Diffuse etc... I do have proper Normal Maps and Parallax Maps, made via Crazy Bump and Gimp).

Also, when I am baking the texture image in Blender, I am in Cycles Render - Object and Image are selected.

I am including screenshots for examples. Any help would be immensely appreciated. [image: Unbaked Texture in Blender][image: Baked Texture in Unity3D][image: Rock Texture Baked in Unity3D, Same method, no scaling]

Comment: Do you have multiple UV coordinate sets on your model? If so, make sure Unity uses the correct one.